# how to get data from api by restkit

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

I start with restkit and have a simple post to send to the api:

```
http://myapi.com/api/stats
```

post paramter: `format=json`

The api returns:

```
{"cache_count":121,"user_count":322,"apps_count":1,"apps_active":47}
```

Could you give me a some example how to use restkit in my case ?

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://myapi.com"];
    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:url];
    NSDictionary *tmp = @{@"format": @"json"};

    [manager postObject:tmp path:@"/okapi/services/apisrv/stats" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            NSDictionary *result = [mappingResult dictionary];

            if([[result objectForKey:@"success"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]){

                // some code
            }
        }

        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];
```

but I get error:

```
Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded."
```

Comment: Can you show any code for what you have tried so far?  What specific problem are you having?

Comment: The RestKit github page can give you an example. Try something and then ask about any problem you have.

Comment: You need both a request descriptor and a response descriptor defined. Do you have either of those?